# How to listen on <select> change events in materialize css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, materialize

A simple **jquery** listener on change doesn't seem to work when use a materialize css select dropdown.

```
 $("#somedropdown").change(function() {
         alert("Element Changed");
      });
```

1) How can I add a listener to detect when a materialize select element has changed?

2) How do I get the select value in that case?

Comment: i guess jquery work in every framework css, can you make simple demo in codepen or fiddle

Comment: If you add your `$("#somedropdown")`-Element dynamically, try `$(document).on("change", "#somedropdown", function() {});`

Answer (score 12):

Add an id to select

```
 <select id="select1">
  <optgroup label="team 1">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="team 2">
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Bind event listener through jquery using the id

```
$("#select1").on('change', function() {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

Hope this helps :-)

[JSFiddle Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunkumarpalaniappan/pwj4qcnj/)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how you are setting up the listener, but I tried out a basic case in codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVZZYy.

It definitely can detect changes as long as you place event listener onto the `<select>` element itself.

Comment: Not working and even option is not getting selected.. Better to put your code here as link can be expired.

Answer (score 2):

As you might know materialize adds it's own `data-select-id` so any Id you add to the `select` element will make it behave a bit unstable, what you can do is wrap your select element with a div and give it an ID then use jQuery to select that id and chain the select element like so..

```
<div id="select1">
 <select >
  <optgroup label="team 1">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="team 2">
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
</div>
```

and

```
$('#select1 select').on('change', function(){
    console.log("option selected!")
    // do your stuff here.
})
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I am using materialize-css with angular7. This is how I have handled this

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select #qwcSelect (change)="optionChanged($event)">
        <option value="" selected disabled>{{placeHolder}}</option>
        // options
    </select>
    <label>{{label}}</label>
</div>
```

and in my component

```
optionChanged(event) {
   console.log(`Selected Value ${event.target.value}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, materialze.css change a `<select>` into a fake select based on a `<ul>` and multiple `<li>`, you can try to bind events on the generated `<li>` but it seems difficult : you can't bind a `onchange` event on a materialize.css `<select>` if you don't use the `browser-default` class or don't search a little.

Answer (score 0):

Add change event listener when you initialize material select

```
$(document).ready(function(){          
          $('#somedropdown').material_select(someScope.someEvent.bind(someScope));
});
```